# Connect Linux server via Windows CMD

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, windows-shell

As we know, we can connect to a Linux server on a Linux or Unix system by typing

```
"SSH username@domain.name.whatever".
```

But it seems like we cannot do things like this by Windows Command Prompt. I mean we cannot connect to a Linux shell by a simple command right?
Just want to make sure if this is impossible without installing extra tools(like sftpc or anything). And please give me some explanation of this.

Comment: You need to install extra tools.

Comment: Cygwin provides CLI ssh, PLink.exe is another option for command execution w/o a shell.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/191140/best-ssh-program-for-windows/191142#191142

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows doesn't have built-in tools for ssh, sftp, scp, etc. You'll have to install something like **cygwin** or invoke other external tools like **putty** with a command. It does have a telnet client though, so if your linux server is local (and security is not an issue) and it allows telnet, you could use telnet from the Windows command line for a painful experience.

Answer (score -2):

There are various ways to run an SSH shell in a browser plugin or even using AJAX if you're running a web server on the linux box.  Just google "browser based ssh" or similar.  Disclaimer: I always just use PuTTY or cygwin, so I've never tried a browser solution.